# In VirtualBox what Solaris version to select for installing Solaris 10 1/13?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, unix, solaris, solaris-10

My operating system is Windows 7. I am new to Unix. I want to install Solaris 10 on VirtualBox.

I have installed VirtualBox 5.1.14.

I have also downloaded Solaris 10 1/13 as **sol-10-u11-ga-x86-dvd.iso**.

Now in VirtualBox I am trying to create a Virtual Machine. In the "Create Virtual Machine" window, when I select "**Solaris**" as "Type", then there are 2 options available as "**Version**" which are:

1. **Oracle Solaris 10 5/09 and earlier (32-bit)**
2. **Oracle Solaris 10 10/09 and later (32-bit)**

I am confused which option to select which matches with the Solaris 10 1/13 I have downloaded?

What is the meaning of 1/13 and 5/09 and 10/09 for Solaris 10?

Thanks

Comment: You can generally look up the release with update number (e.g. 10 u11) in a table to find the month/year of that release. However that release is too new for the table I normally use (https://trent.utfs.org/wiki/Solaris/Releases), but the one on the Solaris wikipedia page mentions that Solaris 10 "u11" is 1/13 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)#Version_history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Updates to Solaris (...) in the past (...) were named after the month and year of their release, such as "Solaris 10 1/13"

[Solaris (operating system) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system))

So you need to set it to **Oracle Solaris 10 10/09 and later**.

BTW, it's much easier and faster to download directly VirtualBox template ([Solaris 10](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/vmtemplates-vmvirtualbox-1949721.html), [Solaris 11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/vm-templates-2245495.html)) from Oracle, you just need to open it in VirtualBox, instead of installing.

Comment: Are Solaris 10 VirtualBox templates available?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I linked to them. Please ignore `solaris11` inside URL, this link goes to Solaris 10.

Comment: so 5/09 means released in May 2009, 10/09 means released in October 2009 and 1/13 means released in January 2013? This is cool.